# How to aggregate values by time in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sum values by time.
time epoch is 10sec and I want to make it 1minute.

### Following data are given.

```
       Date       Time      X
0   2017-10-15  12:50:00    10
1   2017-10-15  12:50:10    20
2   2017-10-15  12:50:20    30
3   2017-10-15  12:50:30    20
4   2017-10-15  12:50:40    10
5   2017-10-15  12:50:50    10
```

### and I want to make it like this.

```
       Date       Time      X
0   2017-10-15  12:50:00    100
1   2017-10-15  12:51:00    300
```

I read this file with pandas.
so the type of Time variable is **`pandas.core.series.Series`**.
And I tried to use `df.resample()`, but it didn't work.
What can I do here??
Thanks for your help.

Comment: For formatting of samples use 4 spaces ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `DatetimeIndex` first:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date')) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('Time'))
print (df)
                      X
2017-10-15 12:50:00  10
2017-10-15 12:50:10  20
2017-10-15 12:50:20  30
2017-10-15 12:50:30  20
2017-10-15 12:50:40  10
2017-10-15 12:50:50  10
```

And then working `resample` very nice:

```
df1 = df.resample('1T').sum()
print (df1)
                       X
2017-10-15 12:50:00  100
```

For columns from `DatetimeIndex` use:

```
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1.index.date, df1.index.time], names=('Date','Time'))

df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
        Date      Time    X
0 2017-10-15  12:50:00  100
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I'd like to remain Date,Time variables separately as it was?? How should I do??

Comment: ok, so are they all connected??
I mean those 3 grey boxes are related?
um.. I have an error 'KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: @DosanHwang - No it, is separate columns.

Comment: bbb.index = pd.to_datetime(bbb.pop('Date')) + pd.to_timedelta(bbb.pop('Time'))
print (bbb) <br/>         

my dataFrame is bbb
'KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: Yes, what is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: @DosanHwang - OK, thanks, it seems there are not date and time columns, is possible get `print (df.head(3).to_dict())` ?

Comment: @DosanHwang - OK, so there are no date and no time column, so it is reason why it not working.

Comment: @jezreal you are genius!! It works , I don't know the reason though.